# Import existing static website structure into a JSON object using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, sitemap

I am creating an online tool which will require the user to import the website structure (i.e. pages and how they relate to each other) from an existing static html website.

As this functionality will be used to import legacy websites, it needs to work without an existing sitemap.xml file.

For example, for a simple website like http://www.jssor.com/demos/index.html the extracted json array should look something like this:

```
{
   name: "Responsive jQuery Image Slider",
   children: [{
          name: 'Development',
          children: [..insert-sub-pages-here..]
      }, {
          name: 'Demos'
      }, {
          name: 'Download'
      }
   ]
}
```

**I am really unsure how to go about this problem.**

Any suggestions on how I should approach this challenge would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why my questions was down voted? Please explain.

Comment: Here's a guess. First, you are asking twice for off-site resources ("Is there an existing framework...", "Is their [sic] a third party service..."). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), number 5. Second, "Should I be going..." and "Is their [sic] a way to ask [...] from an apache server" are really two *different* questions. The Apache one might be good to ask on its own, if it does not have any of the flaws mentioned in the help page I've linked to earlier. I doubt that the first one can be asked without being "too-broad" or "opinion-based."

Comment: @Louis thanks for the feedback. I removed the section where I have asked for any off-site resources. The set of questions, you are referring to were just intended to show some of the thought processes I was going through before posting this question. 
In regards to my original question, I am just looking for a general idea how to approach this problem - something I don't think is off-topic to this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you use basic webpage scraping techniques. an awesome tool for this is *cheerio* - think of it as a query like syntax for headless servers.
you can find a [nice beginners tutorial on the subject here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs)

if cheerio is missing anything you need (scraping dynamic content etc. you can also take a look at casperjs - in essence a full blown headless browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cheerio looks pretty cool. Doesn't look like this is going to be an easy task though.